# if $U(x,y)$ dont satisfy in laplacian equation then how to prove $\nexists Q$: $\nabla Q=(-U_{y},U_{x}) $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

assume $U:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $U\in\mathbb C^2$ and $U_{xx}+U_{yy}\neq0$ how prove there is no function like $Q:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $$\nabla Q=(-U_{y},U_{x}) $$  $\nabla Q$ mean  $\nabla Q=(Q_{x},Q_{y})$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(Q_x,Q_y)=(-U_y,U_x)$. Then we have
$$\Delta Q=Q_{xx}+Q_{yy}=-U_{yx}+U_{xy}=0\,,$$
by Young theorem, that is, $Q$ is *harmonic*. By the [basic properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Connections_with_complex_function_theory) of harmonic functions on $\Bbb R^2$, (around each point there's a neighborhood where) we have $Q(x,y)=\Re(f(x+iy))$ for a holomorphic complex function $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$. [Take $g(x+iy):=Q_x(x,y)-i\,Q_y(x,y)$, this will satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and let $f:=\int g$.]

Now let $P$ be the *harmonic conjugate* of $Q$ (i.e. $P:=\Im(f)$). The Cauchy-Riemann equations say just
$$(Q_x,Q_y)=(P_y,-P_x)\,. $$
So, we have $(-U_y,U_x)=(P_y,-P_x)$, and hence $\nabla (P+U)=0$. But then ($P+U=$ constant, and) $\Delta U=U_{xx}+U_{yy}=-P_{xx}-P_{yy}=-\Delta P=0$, as $P$ is  harmonic, too. -QED-